# How to fetch oracle type NUMBER as string or int/uint?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, odpi-c

I'm fetching a row from oracle database using ODPI-C in C++ and NUMBER(19,0) type appears to be double, so in some cases the field value comes corrupted (e.g. in db viewer shows 5187413295700**304461** but after fetch it's transformed into 5.187413295700**2998**e+18 which is not quite correct).

Reading the field value is done by

```
int dpiStmt_getQueryValue(dpiStmt *stmt, uint32_t pos, dpiNativeTypeNum *nativeTypeNum, dpiData **data);
```

which return parameter **dpiNativeTypeNum nativeTypeNum** is set to **DPI_ORACLE_TYPE_NUMBER**

The return parameter **dpiQueryInfo info** of

```
int dpiStmt_getQueryInfo(dpiStmt *stmt, uint32_t pos, dpiQueryInfo *info);
```

function indicates that field should be read asDouble.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure but in OCI (of which wrapper is ODPI-C) there is a function called `OCINumberToText`. I suppose that this kind of function is what I need.

Also there is a class ResultSet which has member function called `getString(unsigned int colIndex)` which does exactly what I need (converts NUMBER(19,0) to std::string).

**UPDATE 2**

I found a member field called dpiDataTypeInfo.ociTypeCode with a comment "Specifies the OCI type code for the data, which can be useful if the type is not supported by ODPI-C"
from here
https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/structs/dpiDataTypeInfo.html#dpidatatypeinfo

but how to use this for calling OCI functions ?

Comment: The best place to ask ODPI-C questions is on https://github.com/oracle/odpi/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows can be fetch using `dpiVar*`s. Simply before `dpiStmt_fetch` I defined dpi_Var* using this call

```
dpiStmt_defineValue(statement, 1, DPI_ORACLE_TYPE_NUMBER, DPI_NATIVE_TYPE_BYTES, 0, 0, nullptr)
```

You can notice that in that call oracle type is set to DPI_ORACLE_TYPE_NUMBER but native type is set to DPI_NATIVE_TYPE_BYTES.

After fetch the data is acquired using `dpiStmt_getQueryValue`, and read asBytes.